# Android removing newline characters

Tags: android

```
TextUtils.StringSplitter splitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter('\n');
    splitter.setString(tweetMessage);
    tweetMessage = "";
    for (String s : splitter) 
    {
        Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Spliter :: "+ s);
        tweetMessage +=s;
    }
```

But this shows up the newline characters as Squares how do I get Rid of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters you're seeing as squares probably aren't `'\n'` (`'\u000A'`) characters.

If you're seeing a multiple lines in your output then it's possible that multiple characters are being used to split the lines.  It might be `'\r\n'` but it could be something else.

Your best bet is to use a debugger to check exactly what the String contains before you split it.  Or you could add some debug code like so:

```
for (int u : tweetMessage.toCharArray()) {
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.format("\\u%04X",u));
}
```

If you see `\u000D \u000A` then your lines are separated by `"\r\n"`.  This means you can't use a `SimpleStringSplitter` to split the string since that will only split on a single character.

If you don't want to parse the string manually, you could use the [`String.split()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
for (String s : tweetMessage.split("\r\n") {
    //do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove newline/tab characters at the beginning and the end of a string (not the ones in the middle of the string) just use [`.trim()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) function to do the tric. This will remove white spaces from the begging and the end of the string.

Ex:

```
String xmlVersionDate = rootNode.getChildNodeWithName("last-updated").getValue().trim();
```